# Does IIS W3WP use non-blocking I/O to serve static content?

Tags: iis, web-server

Let's say...

IIS is serving a static .MP3 resource that is 10MB in size. The request for the resource comes in to HTTP.sys and is sent to the appropriate W3WP process to handle. The worker process then grabs a thread from the pool to process this request. Now, from my assumption, said thread is going to be I/O bound while it reads the .MP3 resource from disk. Is this accurate? Each time a request comes in for this item, a thread from the pool is reading the same content from disk? Does W3WP use non-blocking I/O to get the item?

Next, let's say there are 1000 simultaneous requests for the same .MP3 file; because of size compared to other requested resources, can this cause impacts to the site? Slowness, queuing, etc?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question about non-blocking disk I/O, but if IIS caches the file then you won't have to worry about it.  You'll need to tweak the config to get it to cache a file that big.  I think the default max file size for caching is 256KB.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on how you write your web service or application.  And it's important that we agree on what "non-blocking" or "asynchronous" means in this context.

Generally, no, w3wp.exe does not use asynchronous I/O calls when retrieving files from storage for serving static content. But of course that doesn't mean w3wp.exe is just completely dead because it happens to be serving a 10MB file at the moment. Each worker process (of which there can be many simultaneous instances running on a server,) each has an entire threadpool, including threads dedicated for I/O operations, at its disposal.

[image: CreateFile]

When a user requests a static file from IIS over the web, w3wp.exe issues an IRP_MJ_CREATE (CreateFile API) for the requested file. (This may come from a hard drive, or it may come from a file cache but that is irrelevant to this question.) The IRP_MJ_CREATE operation is issued with the option "Generic Read," which according to the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff566424(v=vs.85).aspx), is actually this set of options:

> STANDARD_RIGHTS_READ, FILE_READ_DATA, FILE_READ_ATTRIBUTES, FILE_READ_EA, and **SYNCHRONIZE.**

The SYNCHRONIZE option is the interesting one here:

> • For a caller to synchronize an I/O completion by waiting for the returned FileHandle, the SYNCHRONIZE flag must be set. Otherwise, a caller that is a device or intermediate driver must synchronize an I/O completion by using an event object.

You can use this same CreateFile API for asynchronous I/O as well, but you can tell that this is not an asynchronous call because the OVERLAPPED flag is not being used.

> CreateFile provides for creating a file or device handle that is
>   either synchronous or asynchronous. A synchronous handle behaves such
>   that I/O function calls using that handle are blocked until they
>   complete, while an asynchronous file handle makes it possible for the
>   system to return immediately from I/O function calls, whether they
>   completed the I/O operation or not. As stated previously, this
>   synchronous versus asynchronous behavior is determined by specifying
>   FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED within the dwFlagsAndAttributes parameter.

So, yes, a thousand users all simultaneously downloading a 10MB file from your website can cause a performance impact to your server.  IIS's primary strategy for addressing this is by using tons of threads. Thread exhaustion and thread pool tuning and sizing are real things that IIS administrators need to know about.  If you have a really huge website you may even get in to the game of moving your static content to a separate farm of webservers because of I/O bound versus compute bound, etc.  IIS performance tuning is a very complicated topic and this specific Serverfault answer is pretty pedantic in the grand scheme of things. For instance, it *is* possible to use asynchronous handlers in IIS. It depends on how you write your web service/application.

Comment: Thank you for detailed response. Can I ask what a good source would be to read about the internals? If you know of one.

Comment: I would start with *Windows Internals, 6th Ed.* by Mark Russinovich et al first, since IIS runs on Windows and must ultimately operate within the bounds of Windows. If someone wrote a book for IIS that was half as good as *Windows Internals* is for Windows, I would buy it without a second thought. IIS has many more layers of complexity and idiosyncrasy on top of that though... for instance, we didn't even talk about the various caches for static content that IIS has, and their effects on I/O.